# LINESTRING to gpx

Tags: gpx, wkt

I have to following situation:

I got some tracks as a LINESTRING (well-known text) and I need each of them in a separate gpx-file. All of them are stored in a csv file.

Do you have some ideas to get there? I didn't find any scripts or something else to convert from LINESTRING to gpx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html), which supports both [CSV](http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html) and [GPX](http://www.gdal.org/drv_gpx.html) drivers. With your source CSV files, make sure the heading line for the geometry data is named "WKT".